# How do i Integrate Android Alarm Manager?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm building a remainder app where user's schedules' times are stored in Sqflite database in DateTime format.

How do I integrate the Dart's `android_alarm_manager` to the app so that users get alarm when the time they picked in the schedule reaches?

I tried checking the app example but couldn't found it useful. I'd appreciate if someone could guide me or help with link to a tutorial/video.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are probably looking for is `oneShotAt`. It lets you set `DateTime time`. The [DateTime](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) your user would select from the schedule.

- [/android_alarm_manager/lib/android_alarm_manager.dart#L196](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/android_alarm_manager/lib/android_alarm_manager.dart#L196)

So just reusing the basic example from [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager):

```
await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShotAt(dateTime, helloAlarmID, printHello);
```